# Validations errors in view

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using the 4.1 backpack and I have a problem with the validation errors, they are not shown in the view, I have enabled GroupedErrors and InlineErrors, doing some tests I see that the problems come from my $fillable attributes, when they have more than 30 fields they are not show the group of errors, otherwise it is shown.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for quite some time before arriving at the answer. If you are using the wrapper attribute for additional formatting, you need to include the form-group class in your wrapper, since the validation message attaches to that class. Here is an example:

```
CRUD::field('twitter')->wrapper(['class' => 'col-6 pb-3 form-group']);
```

If I include the form-group class, the validation message appears like so:

[image]